# How to use an @expo-google-font as a global decorator in Storybook for react native?

Tags: react-native, expo, storybook, google-fonts

On my root file, I'm importing a Nunito Sans font like so:

```
import { useFonts, NunitoSans_400Regular, NunitoSans_700Bold } from '@expo-google-fonts/nunito-sans';

function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    NunitoSans_400Regular,
    NunitoSans_700Bold,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (...rest of app)
```

This works great and allows me to create a theme for the themeprovider and just name the font family there, like so:

```
declare module '@rneui/themed' {
  export interface TextProps {
    bold?: boolean;
  }

  export interface ComponentTheme {
    Text: Partial<TextProps>;
  }
}

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    Text: ({ bold = false }) => ({
      style: {
        fontFamily: bold ? 'NunitoSans_700Bold' : 'NunitoSans_400Regular',
      },
    }),
  },
});

export default theme;
```

The problem comes when coding in storybook. I'm not sure how to implement this method as a decorator. I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
import { useFonts, NunitoSans_400Regular, NunitoSans_700Bold } from '@expo-google-fonts/nunito-sans';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export const WithCustomFonts = ({ children }) => {
    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        NunitoSans_400Regular,
        NunitoSans_700Bold,
    });

    if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return null;
    }

    return children;
};
```

and then in the preview.js file:

```
import { addDecorator } from "@storybook/react-native";
import ThemeDecorator from "./themeDecorator";
import { WithCustomFonts } from "./withCustomFont";

export const parameters = {
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};

addDecorator(ThemeDecorator)
addDecorator(WithCustomFonts)
```

This causes the text component to just... not appear at all.

What can I do to get this to work? I'm glad it works in my react native app but I like building my components in Storybook so its a little annoying not to see the right font.

Comment: You shouldn't use the add decorator function anymore, you should export a decorators array like export const decorators = [ThemeDecorator, WithCustomFonts]